# Any way to hide source code of embedded Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I run a financial website and i would like to share some spreadsheets with my paid members.  But when embedding spreadsheets using google docs, i'm able to easily view the source code of the doc, which is readily viewable to a user.  I guess aside from the encrypting kind of stuff are there any ingenious ways to prevent users from viewing this link?   Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sharing a Google Spreadsheet containing a script with a workgroup so they can use it, but not modify it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28413397/sharing-a-google-spreadsheet-containing-a-script-with-a-workgroup-so-they-can-us)

Answer (score 0):

How about exporting it as a PDF?

Comment: thanks, but there are docs that i would like to edit and update and that the viewer could revisit, without me uploading a new sheet